# Where/how to store custom functions (or methods) in CakePHP

Tags: function, cakephp, methods, cakephp-1.3

i need to have several functions in cakephp application (for some regular expression matching).

which is best way to store them, so i can access to them in every controller action?

tnx in adv!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you store the functions in the `AppController` class.  All of your controller classes inherit from this controller.

Also create the `app_controller.php` file in the root folder of your application if you have not already.

Comment: He didn't specify that he wanted them in a controller or otherwise. Since we don't know if these are helpers, components, libs/vendors or anything else you shouldn't blindly suggest he fatten up his app_controller.

Comment: I am perfectly aware and was perfectly aware that there were other options to accomplishing this goal (e.g. components, vendors, etc.).  My intent was to provide the simplest answer given the minimal amount of information provided to me in the question. He accepted it, so this worked for him.

Answer (score 4):

Or, if the actions aren't typical controller actions - you could store them in either a component (available to controllers) then include the component in your AppController.. or you could put the file in the vendors folder and use App::import to load the file into the bootstrap.php