# Where implement query functions in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, structure, layer

The CakePHP framework is a layered structure. My question is:

Where (theoretically) is the best place to implement data query functions? In models or controllers?

With "data query functions" I mean functions like `getItemsWithSomeInfo($idItem)` etc., i.e functions that are not actions.

Currently, I am implementing these functions in the controller, but I think there are other frameworks in which these functions (or methods) are implemented in the model layer.

I searched on Stackoverflow and found similar issues ([Where/how to store custom functions (or methods) in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074827/where-how-to-store-custom-functions-or-methods-in-cakephp)), but (in my opinion) are not good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its better to place such functions in your Model then in Controllers. All data related codes should be in the model. It is always a better idea in the long run, when it comes to refactoring or testing. You know exactly where to find the code. And it can be re-used without copy & paste in other actions/controllers.

Comment: Hi @Sudhir, I like your answer, is what I expected. However, I would like some response to make sure. Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

Place you function in your corresponding model and then use it in your controller:

Example:

**In Model.php**

```
public function getItemsWithSomeInfo($idItem) {
  // your code
}
```

**In ModelsController.php**

```
$this->Model->getItemsWithSomeInfo($id);
```